# Toast The method makeText(context, charSequance, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the argument (multiFunction,String, int)

Tags: performance, android-intent

I'm new to android development, I have created a new class called multiFunction and created two functions for Toast but I'm getting an error says: The method makeText(context, charSequance, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the argument (multiFunction,String, int)

```
package com.s.smart;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class multiFunction {
//function to generate toast message

public void longMessage(String yourMessage){
    Toast.makeText(multiFunction.this,yourMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
public void shortMessage(String yourMessage){
    Toast.makeText(multiFunction.this,yourMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue....

```
package com.s.smart;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class multiFunction {
    private Context context;
    public multiFunction(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
//function to generate toast message

    public void longMessage(String yourMessage){
        Toast.makeText(this.context,yourMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void shortMessage(String yourMessage){
        Toast.makeText(this.context,yourMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```